# Mirth Monitor Queue and Send Email

Tags: javascript, email, mirth

I'm working with Mirth Connect Server 3.7.0. My code is below. I have it in postprocessor. I'm just trying to monitor the queue and send a message after it gets to x number of messages waiting. When this script executes, I am receiving the following message:

[2023-03-16 02:30:13,037]  ERROR  (com.mirth.connect.server.util.javascript.JavaScriptUtil:522): Error executing Postprocessor script from channel: f737be65-9f12-4e54-bab2-52c2491aeb27
com.mirth.connect.server.MirthJavascriptTransformerException: SOURCE CODE:
144: 145:

```
//emBody = emBody + 'Message Sent at ' + rightnow + ' \n';146: 147: 

var smtpConn = SMTPConnectionFactory.createSMTPConnection();    

//Opens email connection using email settings in your Mirth Connect Settings.148: 149: 

smtpConn.send(emTo,emCC,emFrom,emSubj,emBody);150: 151: 

globalMap.put(channelId + '_lastalert',rightnow);152: 
153: 

LINE NUMBER:
149DETAILS:
Wrapped java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at f737be65-9f12-4e54-bab2-52c2491aeb27_Postprocessor:149 (doScript)
at f737be65-9f12-4e54-bab2-52c2491aeb27_Postprocessor:165
at com.mirth.connect.server.util.javascript.JavaScriptUtil.executeScript(JavaScriptUtil.java:547)
at com.mirth.connect.server.util.javascript.JavaScriptUtil.executePostprocessorScripts(JavaScriptUtil.java:275)
at com.mirth.connect.server.transformers.JavaScriptPostprocessor$JavaScriptPostProcessorTask.doCall(JavaScriptPostprocessor.java:104)
at com.mirth.connect.server.util.javascript.JavaScriptTask.call(JavaScriptTask.java:113)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:614)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
at com.mirth.connect.server.util.ServerSMTPConnection.send(ServerSMTPConnection.java:119)
at com.mirth.connect.server.util.ServerSMTPConnection.send(ServerSMTPConnection.java:156)
at com.mirth.connect.server.userutil.SMTPConnection.send(SMTPConnection.java:270)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor243.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1479)
at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:815)
at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:109)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:405)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3508)
at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:120)
at com.mirth.connect.server.util.javascript.JavaScriptTask.executeScript(JavaScriptTask.java:150)
at com.mirth.connect.server.util.javascript.JavaScriptUtil.executeScript(JavaScriptUtil.java:542)
... 7 more
```

```
var rightnow = new Date();                                      //Current Datetime

var hLimit = 23;                                                    //Number of hours before resending

var lastsent = globalMap.get(channelId + '_lastalert');

var datediff = (rightnow - lastsent) / (1000 * 60 * 60);                    //calculates hours since last alert went out

if (datediff < hLimit) {

return;

} else {

   //var controller = Packages.com.mirth.connect.server.controllers.ChannelUtil.getInstance();

   var channelName = ChannelUtil.getChannelName(channelId);

   //var stats = controller.getStatistics(channelId);
   
   var mSent = ChannelUtil.getSentCount(channelId);

   var mReceived = ChannelUtil.getReceivedCount(channelId);
   
   var mQueued = ChannelUtil.getQueuedCount(channelId);

   var mError = ChannelUtil.getErrorCount(channelId);

   var qAlarm = 100;                                               //This is the limit of queued messages prior to triggering the alert

   if (mQueued >= qAlarm) {

       var emTo = 'none@email.com';    

       var emCC = 'none@email.com';                                                //This is any cc emails you want to include

       var emFrom = 'none@email.com';                                                  //This is the “From” address that will appear on your email

       var emSubj = 'Queue Alert for Channel (TEST): ' + channelName;              //This is the subject of the email  
   
       var emBody = 'Queued messages detected on channel (TEST) ' + channelName + '.\n';

       //emBody = emBody + 'Current number of queued messages is ' + mQueued.toString() + '.\n';

       //emBody = emBody + 'This alert will not be resent for ' + hLimit.toString() + ' hours.\nPlease do not respond to this email. This address is not monitored.\n';

       //emBody = emBody + 'Message Sent at ' + rightnow + ' \n';

       var smtpConn = SMTPConnectionFactory.createSMTPConnection();            //Opens email connection using email settings in your Mirth Connect Settings.

       smtpConn.send(emTo,emCC,emFrom,emSubj,emBody);

       globalMap.put(channelId + '_lastalert',rightnow);
   
       
   
   }
   

   
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas or could you point me in the right direction?? Thanks so much in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the SMTP Sender destination in a separate channel and route it there?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34780902)